# flutter-desktop-embedding - how to generate "build/flutter_assets"

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

Build https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding ok.

The embedding uses a `build/flutter_assets` from the Flutter project to embed. https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/blob/master/linux/example/flutter_embedder_example.cc#L35

But how in a Flutter project is this generated?

with `flutter build` ?

Actually I managed to build `build/flutter_assets` once and the embedding worked (cool stuff), but now I can't reproduce anymore, little strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The make of the linux lib executes a flutter build command of the example project.

Just picking this flutter build command generates `build/flutter_assets` in the flutter project to embed. The command is:

```
flutter build flx \
 --local-engine-src-path=../../engine/src \
 --local-engine=host_debug_unopt
```

---

Was solved by this issue https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/issues/19